# 2 MAAS region controllers one database hot_standby read only errors

Tags: maas, postgresql

I have 2 MAAS region controllers up and running. I am using MAAS 2.0 on ubuntu 16.04. I got the posgresql streaming setup in the hot_standby configuration. I was able to get load balancing working with both servers and I got the VIP setup and working. The problem is, when I stop the postgresql database service on the master server, the standby takes over, but it gets very strange results. If you keep refreshing the web interfaces you will get some of the MAAS screens, but not with all the data. The postgresql log gets a ton of read_only errors.

I am using this tutorial: https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/ha.html

Is there a way to get MAAS to run normally with the read_only hot_standby database on the standby node?

Standby log errors:

```
2016-12-26 14:41:50 CST [3646-1] maas@maasdb ERROR:  cannot execute LISTEN during recovery
2016-12-26 14:41:50 CST [3646-2] maas@maasdb STATEMENT:  LISTEN device_create;
2016-12-26 14:41:50 CST [3647-1] maas@maasdb ERROR:  cannot execute LISTEN during recovery
2016-12-26 14:41:50 CST [3647-2] maas@maasdb STATEMENT:  LISTEN config_create;
2016-12-26 14:41:50 CST [3655-1] maas@maasdb ERROR:  cannot execute LISTEN during recovery
2016-12-26 14:41:50 CST [3655-2] maas@maasdb STATEMENT:  LISTEN space_create;
2016-12-26 14:41:51 CST [3606-1] maas@maasdb ERROR:  cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction
2016-12-26 14:41:51 CST [3606-2] maas@maasdb STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM "maasserver_bootsourcecache" WHERE "maasserver_bootsourcecache"."boot_source_id" = 1
2016-12-26 14:41:51 CST [3657-1] maas@maasdb ERROR:  cannot execute LISTEN during recovery
2016-12-26 14:41:51 CST [3657-2] maas@maasdb STATEMENT:  LISTEN sshkey_create;
2016-12-26 14:41:51 CST [3593-3] maas@maasdb ERROR:  cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction
2016-12-26 14:41:51 CST [3593-4] maas@maasdb STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "maasserver_regioncontrollerprocess" ("created", "updated", "region_id", "pid") VALUES ('2016-12-26T14:41:51.707866'::timestamp, '2016-12-26T14:41:51.707866'::timestamp, 2, 3531) RETURNING "maasserver_regioncontrollerprocess"."id"
```

Thanks for your time,
Chris

Comment: After many many many tests I have come up with a configuration that will achieve what I want to do. I will be posting information on it soon. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the videos and content on how I solved my HA issues.

[HA site](https://sites.google.com/site/openstackinthebasement3/maasha)